# How do I print out one HashMap KeyValue at one time after asking the user if they want to continue?

Tags: java

I think this is working the way that I want but I can't figure how to print out each KeyValue one at a time that is entered only after asking of the user wants to continue. I know it's working because if I run the for loop it prints out what I entered. But I want to be able to call them back one at a time.

I tried to reduce the amount of code I'm showing. The first while loop is working (though I took most of it out), I can't seem to figure out the second while loop.

```
    Map<String, String> pets = new HashMap<>();

        String userInput;
        String name;
        String type;


try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {  

           System.out.println("Would you like to enter another? (y/n) ");

        numberOfPets++;

    } while (scnr.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        System.out.println("You entered " + numberOfPets + " pets.");


        do {
           System.out.println("Enter one of the names of the pets (or type END to quit): ");
            userInput = scnr.nextLine();
            pets.get(userInput);

              for (Map.Entry<String, String> pet : pets.entrySet()) {
              System.out.println(pet.getKey() + " is an " + pet.getValue());
             }

        } while (scnr.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("e"));

    }

I want it to look like this: 
You entered 2 pets.
Enter one of the pets names (or type END to quit): {User enters Aslan}
Aslan is a Lion.
Enter one of the pets names (or type END to quit): {User enters Eustance}
Eustance is a dragon.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> pets = Map.of("a", "lion", "b", "bear", "c", "cat");
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter one letter (or type END to quit): ");
    String userInput = scnr.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(userInput + " is an " + pets.get(userInput));

} while (true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This worked!! However do you know why I am getting an null when I type end? I changed the userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("e") instead of end.

Comment: If you are checking the map before you exit, then the map returns a  `null` if a value doesn't exist for the key `end`

Comment: Oh, I see. So how would I make it so that it's not checking the map when I select end and actually ends?

Comment: Did you see what I did in my example?  I moved the test for end `before` I checked the map.  Then I simply did a 'break' before the loop.

Comment: I got it now! I'm not sure if I was typing something wrong but it's working. Thank you!